# Use an Android tablet as a Wacom drawing tablet for a Mac?

Tags: zoom-cloud-meetings

How do I share Android tablet's screen while attending zoom meeting from Mac? I know there is a zoom plugin to share iPhone/iPad screen but is it possible to do the same with an Android tablet? (using the Android tab as a Wacom tab)?

I have: MacBook Air2020
Galaxy Tab A

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using the Android remote control software [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy):

If you enable Development option on your Android device and afterwards enable the "Android Debug Bridge" option you can connect your Android device to your computer via USB and then remote control the Android device and see it's screen on your computer using a software like [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) (install it on MacOS via `brew install scrcpy`).

Then in a Zoom call you can share your computer screen which shows the Android screen via scrcpy.